# Delphi android deployment too many files

Tags: delphi, deployment

I am trying to deploy 2664 .gif images to Android 64 Release . My app only shows black screen. When I decrease the number of images to half, application works. my app is empty, no codes, just a New blank application. How can i make it work? Thanks...

Comment: I hope you are not loading all those 2664 gif images on application load. If you are then this is probably the reason for black screen as it will take quite some tome for all of them to be loaded. Unless you absolutely need all those images loaded at same time which I doubt you do I strongly suggest you load them at runtime when they are needed and unload them when they are no longer needed. This way you will also avoid your application to be using lots of memory all the time.

Comment: Also are he talking here about animated or static gif images? In both cases you may also consider adding them to larger Atlas Images sometimes also refereed as Sprite Sheets or [Texture atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas). Image Lists actually combine several existing images into such Image Atlas

Comment: I am not trying to load images at startup. I use Delphi 11 to create android applications.   I added 2664 images to apk by using Deployment Manager. I installed the apk but when I open it I only see black screen. There are no commands in the app. App works if I add half of the images to apk.

Comment: As I said since loading of such large number of images takes quite a lot of time it is possible that you have black screen just because your application still hasn't finished loading all of the images. Do note that unless you have designed your application to load images using separate thread the whole application will be unresponsive until loading of all images is finished since you are essentially blocking main thread with the process of loading the images. And if that takes to much time Android may consider your application to be hanged and forcefully terminate it. ...

Comment: ... That is why I suggested you don't load all of the images at application start but only when they are actually needed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that the file be uploaded to the server. So when the application is opened, it downloads some files first and then saves them locally.